# IE10 javascript access xml element issue

Tags: javascript, html, xml, internet-explorer-10

I have 3 files, (htm, xml, js) to work together fine in IE8, but in IE10 the javascript cannot get xml element:

getxml.htm

```
<html>
    <head><title>getxml.htm</title></head>

    <xml id="myxml" src="myxml.xml"></xml>
    <script src="getxml.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

myxml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<publish>
</publish>
```

getxml.js

```
get_xml_content();
function get_xml_content() {
    alert("get_xml_content");
    alert(myxml);       // ie8: [object], ie10: [object HTMLUnknownElement]
    var xmle=myxml.getElementsByTagName("publish").item(0);  
    alert(xmle);        // ie8: [object], ie10: null
}
```

Alert message from IE8 and IE10 are written as comments above in getxml.js.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What is `myxml`? I've never heard of embedding XML documents in HTML like that.

Comment: @Blender Probably because it appears to only work in old ie

Comment: @Blender, This is legacy code, I am trying to make it work on IE10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a blog post at the IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx), IE10 does not support XML Data Islands when running in Standards mode.  This brings IE10 into conformance with how other browsers parse HTML.

To get this to work in IE10, you need to load the page in legacy mode.  You can do that by including the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

A more cross-browser approach would be to link the XML with an `<iframe>` instead:

```
<iframe id="myxml" src="myxml.xml" />
```

Of course, you'll need to hide it with a bit of CSS:

```
iframe { display: none; }
```

Reference `contentDocument` to parse the document:

```
var myxml = document.getElementById("myxml").contentDocument;
var xmle=myxml.getElementsByTagName("publish").item(0);  
alert(xmle);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but I found the content of xml is showing on html now in a frame...

Comment: @EthanLong - Hide it with CSS.