# Need to work around selectSingleNode in IE10

Tags: javascript, xml, prototypejs, internet-explorer-10

My client has a web app that started throwing errors in IE10.  I tracked down the source of the error and it seems IE 10 no longer supports selectSingleNode.  Here's the function where it's used:

```
    ScormApi.prototype.setTom = function( tom ) {
         this.tom = CreateXmlDocument();
         var rootelem = importAllNode( this.tom, this.tomTemplate.documentElement, true );
         this.tom.appendChild( rootelem );
         // Transforms the tracing of the user in tracking template
         // Perform the navigation on all nodes of tom and for each value found
         // Sets it to this.tom
         rootelem = tom.selectSingleNode('//cmi');
         this.parseXML( rootelem, '/' , this, this.setTomParam );
    }
```

It's called with the following code:

```
    var ajxreq = new Ajax.Request(
    this.baseurl+'?op=Initialize',
    {   method: 'post',
         asynchronous:false,
         postBody: strSoap,
         requestHeaders: {
             'Man':"POST " + this.baseurl + " HTTP/1.1",
             'Host':this.host,
             "Content-type":"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
             "SOAPAction":this.serviceid + "Initialize",
             "X-Signature":playerConfig.auth_request
         }
    });

    if( ajxreq.transport.status == 200 ) {
         try {
             this.setTom( ajxreq.transport.responseXML );
         }
    }
```

I found suggestions to change the response type to msxml-document, use querySelector or use jQuery's find function, but I can't piece together how to actually implement it in this prototype framework.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note, this solution only works if you don't need features from IE 10.  But if you have a site that worked fine until IE 10 came along and you just want it to work again, I found this other answer on [IE10 javascript access xml element issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871092/ie10-javascript-access-xml-element-issue)

Basically you just put in a meta tag to tell IE 10 to treat your site as if it is IE9 and it works again.

In PHP, if you want to only put the tag in if it's IE10, you can do this:

```
$isIE10 = (bool) preg_match('/(?i)msie [10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if ($isIE10) echo '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />';
```

Answer (score 2):

As for http://doogalbellend.blogspot.fr/2012/04/cross-browser-selectsinglenode-for-xml.html

> Update – This no longer works in IE10, since selectSingleNode has been removed from the XML document returned from AJAX calls. This can be worked around by setting the response type of the XmlHttpRequest, like so :
>
> xhr.responseType =  'msxml-document';

Modifying your request by adding `responseType: 'msxml-document'` in the options should work.

Comment: do you mean add it on the same level as method, postBody etc?  Also, should I leave the xhr prefix on?

Comment: As I said, modifying your Request options (the object where you set the asynchroneous, postBody ... vars) add the property: `responseType: 'msxml-document'`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried changing the request, but it still says that it does not support selectSingleNode. I added the response type after the postBody like so: `postBody: strSoap,responseType: 'msxml-document',`

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm supposed to be creating a replacement for the SelectSingleNode function, but I'm not sure how when calling it from where all of the functions seem to be created with the ScormApi.prototype format.  So I tried changing the first line of the doogalbellend solution to `ScormApi.prototype.SelectSingleNode = function() {` but I'm not sure how to modify the `rootelem = tom.selectSingleNode('//cmi');` line where the function is called.

Comment: I also tried creating the function exactly as shown and changing the function call to SelectSingleNode to use the same capitalization.  So I'm either missing an aspect of the solution or the solution is not working.

Comment: I tried one more thing.  I replaced the line `return xmlDoc.selectSingleNode(elementPath); ` line from the doogalbellend solution with `alert(xmlDoc);` and I stopped getting the message about the object not support selectSingleNode.  So it seems that the document is not evaluating and that's when it tries to use the same not supported function.